# Uploading in laravel 5.6 not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I've tried using this link https://www.5balloons.info/example-file-upload-validation-laravel-5-6/

And I manage to get it working by trying to return the FileName but the problem is the file I'm trying to upload is not showing in the folder "storage/app"

Here is my code

**Controller**

```
public function letterOfIntent(Request $request)
{
    $fileName = "fileName".time().'.'.request()->fileToUpload->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->fileToUpload->storeAs('logos',$fileName);

    return 'success';
}
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="/supplier-information/company-officer/letter-of-intent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-form-method="create">
{{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4">
            <label style="color:tomato;">Letter of Intent</label>           
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="fileToUpload" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
             <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please upload a valid image file. Size of image should not be more than 2MB.</small>                         
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label>Date of Validity</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="upload_file" id="upload_file" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-flat text-contrail">Upload</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-flat text-contrail">View</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `$request->file('fileToUpload')` instead?